bash script to Echo multiple lists
i need to echo multiple list like this
list_0=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
list_1=(7 8 9)
list_2=(22 7 34 88)
.....
.....
list_99=(23 67 80)

I have this version that works but every time I have to declare new list in for comand
for nums in ${list_0[@]} ${list_1[@]} ${list_2[@]} ......... ${list_99[@]}
do
echo $nums
done

Is there any possibility to make it easier to go through the lists ?
something like this
x=0
for nums in ${list_(x until x=99)[@]}
do
echo $nums
done


Thank you

Try: declare -p  ${!list_*}

You could use for num in list_{{0..4},{88..99}}; do ...! Try simply: echo list_{{0..4},{88..99}}!!

To replicate your desired double nested loop using variable dereference:
for i in {0..99}; do v="list_$i[@]"
  for j in "${!v}"; do
    echo "$j"
  done
done

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
22
7
34
88
:
:
23
67
80


or for v in list_{0..99};do ... ;-)

Could use a nameref:
list_0=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
list_1=(7 8 9)
list_2=(22 7 34 88)
list_3=(23 67 80)

for name in list_{0..3}; do
  declare -n arr=$name
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$name" "${arr[*]}"
done

list_0  1 2 3 4 5 6
list_1  7 8 9
list_2  22 7 34 88
list_3  23 67 80

